# Add (not create) remote branches to local repo using git-svn

Tags: git, svn, branch, git-branch, git-svn

I am working on big SVN repository using `git-svn`. Pure `svn` is very slow. I should have cloned my repository using command:
`git svn clone <rep_url> -T trunk/ -b branches/ --no-minimize-url css`

but I did it by
`git svn clone <rep_url> -T trunk/ --no-minimize-url css`

or
`git svn clone <rep_url> -b branches/ --no-minimize-url css`

I don't know exact command I executed

Now I am facing issue because when I do `git branch -a` it shows me only trunk (master) branch:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/trunk
```

I want to see all branches in `git branch -a` output. I have another copy of this same repository and I cloned it using both switches `-T` and `-b`. When I do `git branch -a` in this another repository it shows me list of branches also like:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/trunk
  remotes/origin/branch1
  remotes/origin/branch2
  remotes/origin/branch3
  remotes/origin/branch4
  branch1
  branch2
```

How can I add remote branches to my repository?
Is it possible?

Note that typing `git branch branch1 remotes/origin/branch1` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I have fixed that. I have just compared two .git/config files (one from this repo, and second from repo with branches) and I noticed there is no `branches` key in `[svn-remote "svn"]` section, so after copying that key (branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/origin/*) and typing `git svn fetch` it downloaded all branches. It took for me 5 hours. But after that I can see list of all branches in `git branch -a`
Is modifying config file like that proper / safe solution?